# Checking for an active Facebook Session in viewDidAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, facebook-ios-sdk, rubymotion

I have a `UIViewController` subclass called `HomeController` that is made the `rootViewController` in my `application:applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

My intended logical flow works like this:

1. If the user isn't signed in (determined by whether there's an open, active session using the FB iOS SDK), present a modal view controller asking them to sign in.
2. If they are signed in, display the `HomeController` view as normal.

I do a quick check using `openSessionWithAllowLoginUI(false)` in the app delegate to see whether a cached token exists, as well, which may yield me an active session if the app is reopened after having been closed.

I was placing the session check logic in `viewDidAppear` and presenting my modal view controller to login. But `viewDidLoad` logic still gets executed, and the data obviously isn't there for this to function correctly.

What's a better way to be doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to remove the code using the data from`viewDidLoad`. You can have something like:

```
def viewDidLoad
  self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor # Or anything you want just to create background screen
end

def viewDidAppear(animated)
  if alreadyLoggedIn
    createViewAndDoSomethingWithData
  else
    showLogin
  end
end
```